# SfChart are not displaying on IOS and working properly in Android - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

Syncfusion sfchart working fine in android but generating error in IOS. here is my AppDelegate class code

AppDelegate:

```
namespace ProjectName
{   
    [Register ("AppDelegate")] 
    public class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            new Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.iOS.Renderers.SfChartRenderer();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
            Appearance.Configure ();
            LoadApplication (new App());
            return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove 'new Syncfusion.SFChart.Xforms.IOS.Renderer.SfChartRenderer' from Code it run without generating any error or any result but when I put this line of code then it throw error which is 
foundation.monotouchexception objective-c exception thrown

Comment: Sounds like a Syncfusion bug. I would report it to them using their website

Comment: I've already reported this issue there

Comment: await their response. Only they will be able to fix it as it is most probably a bug in their source code

Answer (score 0):

We were not able to reproduce the reported issue at our end and we have prepared a sample for this. Please check the attached sample.

**Note:** We suggest you to use **Init method of SfChartRenderer** as per the below code.

**Code Example:**

Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.iOS.Renderers.SfChartRenderer.Init();

If you are still facing this issue, please update us the **Xamarin Studio / Visual Studio** version. Please download the sample from the following location.

**Sample:** http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/131907/ze/ChartGettingStarted1268455699

Regards,

Saravana Pandian M.